# Behavior of android OS when both Wifi and Mobile Data are enabled

Tags: android, android-wifi, 3g, 4g

Can someone please tell me how the android OS behaves when **both Wifi and Mobile Data are enabled**? That is when both are enabled in the phone, *which* connection does the phone use?

If it favours Wifi over Mobile Data when both are on, will the mobile data then be *switched off*, meaning that the Mobile data connection, even though is left ON, does it still impact on the phone in terms of **battery drainage, Mobile data money balance, and phone heating**?

Comment: When wifi is connected mobile data is automatically disconnected (in setting it only display status of your choice whether you want it to connect or not. when it accentually connected you will show mobile data up/down arrow in notification bar ). when wifi is not available at that time device automatically connect mobile data.

Answer (score 1):

It uses the faster one.  So it tends to prefer wifi, unless the link speed is very low (you'll sometimes even see it disconnect from wifi on some versions of android if the link speed is too low).

Battery usage-  depends.  Keeping on both radios takes more power, but if you're transfering lots of data using wifi can actually be a power savings, because it will take less time in the transmitting state.  Phone heating is directly correlated with battery usage-  heat is due to spending power.  As for bandwidth caps-  data sent over wifi won't affect your cellular cap.  If your wifi usage has a cap it will affect that.